# Is there a way to configure Alamofire to not dispatch results to the main queue?

Tags: alamofire

I am building with an iOS application framework that is already opinionated about how the output of effects (such as network calls) should be dispatched back to the main queue.

Ergo, using my application framework and Alamofire in stock configuration, I believe Alamofire is dispatching my result to the main queue, and then my application framework is re-dispatching the result to the main queue. This is not a show-stopping problem, but it is a small performance penalty that I do not need to pay, *if* I could configure Alamofire to not perform that final dispatch back to the main queue.

Basically, I would like to configure Alamofire to behave like vanilla URLSession, where it is the caller's responsibility to dispatch back to the main queue.

I have read the Alamofire docs describing the handful of queues you can pass in to an Alamofire Session to configure where different parts of the Alamofire pipeline happen, but I can't quite figure out if there a configuration I can set up to effectively opt out of that last dispatch for the response handler.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of Alamofire's features that dispatch to the main queue can take a specific queue instead, but you can't set a default for all of them at once. For instance, if you want your response handlers to be called on a specific queue, pass that queue to the response handler: `responseDecodable(queue: someQueue)`. Otherwise all of Alamofire's internal events happen on a specific set of queues, such as the `Session`'s `rootQueue`, which you can also use for the other features.

Comment: Hey Jon, thanks for answering. To follow up a bit, because I _have_ to re-dispatch later because of my application framework, what I'm looking for from Alamofire is `.responseDecodable(queue: someAliasForCurrentQueueOfTaskSoNoDispatchHappensAtAll)`. It sounds like I could make a single custom queue and hand it to every part of Alamofire's pipeline, but within Alamofire the dispatch calls _are_ going to happen, even if all the calls are "dispatch from customQueue1 to customQueue1", ie the cost of the dispatch call itself is unavoidable. Is that correct?

Comment: That would be up to Dispatch itself. It may be able to optimize that case since there's no need to queue hop and it would simply enqueue the work onto the queue. Enqueuing work onto a queue is lightweight anyway so there's no need to worry about it.